# How can I precondition a non-linear problem before linearization?

Tags: preconditioning

When I think of solving non-linear equations, I generally think of linearizing first, then applying a preconditioner to the linear matrix.  The thought occurred to me that it might be possible to condition the non-linear equations BEFORE they are linearized.  Are there any general strategies to precondition non-linear equations that are independent of the structure of the system of equations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, any approximate nonlinear solver can be used as a nonlinear preconditioner. For example, if your system has directional stiffness, you could use a 1D shooting method as a preconditioner. [Cai and Keyes' (2002) *Nonlinearly preconditioned inexact Newton algorithms*](http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~cai/papers/pin.pdf) provide another useful example.

In PETSc, nonlinear methods such as [quasi-Newton](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-dev/docs/manualpages/SNES/SNESQN.html), [nonlinear conjugate gradients](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-dev/docs/manualpages/SNES/SNESNCG.html), [nonlinear GMRES](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-dev/docs/manualpages/SNES/SNESNGMRES.html) (aka. Anderson acceleration), and [nonlinear Richardson](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-dev/docs/manualpages/SNES/SNESNRICHARDSON.html) can be used with a nonlinear preconditioner. The nonlinear preconditioner is any other [`SNES`](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-dev/docs/manualpages/SNES/SNES.html) implementation, perhaps a [user-defined "shell"](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-dev/docs/manualpages/SNES/SNESSHELL.html) implementation.

Answer (score 4):

When using a nonlinear conjugate gradient method to solve a square system $F(x)=0$ by minimizing the residual squared norm $\|F(x)\|_2^2$, it usually pays to precondition the system by means of a linear transformation,
e.g., computed by an approximate factorization $LU$ of an approximate Jacobian at the starting point. (Often such an approximate Jacobian is available from a simplification of the problem.) Thus one minimizes instead $\|B F(x)\|_2^2$,
where $B=(LU)^{-1}$, and $r=BF(x)$ is computed by solving $LUr=F(x)$.

At more expense (one new approximate factorization per iteration), one can also minimize $B(x)F(x)$.