# Reference for preconditioning nonlinear conjugate gradient with LU decomposition of jacobian

Tags: preconditioning, conjugate-gradient

When solving non-linear systems of equations, @Arnold Neumaier suggested in [How can I precondition a non-linear problem before linearization?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2237/how-can-i-precondition-a-non-linear-problem-before-linearization) to use an approximate LU decomposition of an approximate Jacobian at the starting point to precondition nonlinear conjugate-gradient to minimize $\|F(x)\|_2^2$. Can anyone point out a reference for this scheme, ideally with convergence results?